# When modeling "Many To One" relation, how can I deal with record from "Many" side not belonging to any of the records on "One" side?

Tags: database-design, nullable, many-to-one

I have a a list of **products** each of which that can belong to a product **category**.

I can make two tables:

```
product(id, product_name, category_id);
category(id, category_name);
```

Some products do not yet have category defined or do not belong to any defined category.  How do I deal with that?

I can make `category_id` nullable, or `category_name` nullable, or both.  Or I can create a "not_yet_assigned" value as part of category_name.

Is there a good solution to this?

Comment: I would create a category called uncategorized.

Comment: Or just allow NULL for category_id?

Comment: @Naruto, that was my plight.  I can NULL `category_id`, but then ... why not create a NULL category and keep `category_id` non-nullable.. and then I got stuck

Comment: @Dennis, that is what I would recommend. Though I'd name it something like `Uncategorized` like @Peter suggested, to keep it unambiguous.

Comment: @Dennis sorry, seems I've overread that part, but then this question is pretty opinion based in my opinion..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the Product.Category_id `nullable` will force to use `outer joins` to see all your products with their Category.Category_Name, so I would avoid that, and I would create a Category called Uncategorized or similar.
 Or perhaps one **Uncategorized** (which would be the default) and one **Other** for those Products that do not belong to any other category.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I think the answer to your problem depends on the fact that you want to distinguish or not between the two cases:

1. A product belongs to a miscellaneous category, or
2. The product has not yet been categorized.

If the distinction is significant for your application, than my advice is to create a category “Miscellaneaous” (or similar), and assign its `id` as foreign key to the first set of product, and leave null for the product that must still be categorized.

If the distinction is not significant than you can leave null the category, or define a "null" category, I think there is no big difference between the two approaches.